# How to set recursive triggers on not on the whole database?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to set recursive triggers on, not by the changing the whole database settings, but for one particular update, or at worst for one particular trigger. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best way for recursive update is using Common Table Expressions:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

If somebody else adds a better solution, I would appreciate it.